# How to invoke passed method which has argument in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to invoke a method with argument received as an argument but not able to do so. Here is what I am trying.

I have a method which gets me alert dialog object like below.

```
fun getAlertDialog(
title: String,
positiveButtonText: String,
positiveClickAction: (() -> Unit)) {
someTextView.setOnClickListener {
positiveClickActin.invoke()
}
```

and the above can be called like below

```
val dialog = getAlertDialog("Title", "Ok", ::clickedOk)
```

considering clickedOk is a void method like below

```
fun clickedOk() {
println("clicked")
}
```

But I am stuck when i want to pass a method with argument. Let's say I want to print some variable. The getSimpleDialog method can be changed as below.

```
fun getAlertDialog(
title: String,
positiveButtonText: String,
positiveClickAction: ((any: Any) -> Unit))
someTextView.setOnClickListener {
positiveClickActin.invoke() //this cannot be achieved now as the method takes an argument
}
```

and call it as

```
val dialog = getSimpleDialog("Hello", "ok", { variable -> println("clicked $variable")})
```

but i cannot invoke this method in the getSimpleDialog's on click listener. How do I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can either call

```
positiveClickActin.invoke(param)
```

or simply,

```
positiveClickActin(param)
```

Similarly for no parameter case you can use

```
positiveClickActin()
```

Instead of calling invoke().

While reading in the [doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#:%7E:text=Since%20Java%20has%20no%20way%20of%20marking%20methods,using%20the%20infix%20call%20syntax%20is%20not%20allowed.), the `invoke()` looks to be useful while having mixed of java and kotlin code. (but I might be wrong here as I am still new in kotlin)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am looking for a way to find that param to pass it. That's where I am stuck. Let me know if you know how  to access that param within the method.